# Storing JSON data inside of a dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, json, dictionary, nsdictionary

I'm trying to store a set of JSON data inside of a dictionary with the following loop:

```
self.result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

                         if(error == nil)

                             self.mapLocations = result;

                             for (NSDictionary  *location in self.mapLocations[@"merchants"]) {

                               for (NSDictionary __strong *locations in location[@"branches"]) {

                                   locations = self.diningDic;
                                   NSLog(@"DiningDic:%@", self.diningDic);
                             }

                         }
                     }
```

I also created an instance variable as you can see, and also declared it as strong within the loop because I kept ending up with an error that said,"fast enumeration variables cannot be stored by default in ARC."

So every time I attempt to print my newly stored dictionary:

```
NSLog(@"%@, self.diningDic);
```

I end up the following error:

```
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
```

Any ideas on why this is happening, and how do I store this JSON data as a dictionary?

Comment: What is `self.diningDic`? Where does it get set? At this point, it does not look related to your `jsonData`.

Comment: Yeah I need another approach here. I've decided to scrap this method, and try another. I'm looping multiple dictionaries here, and that's why I'm getting multiple values here. This is definitely not the most efficient way to gather values. I've decided to go with the tutorial on Ray Wenderlich.